# Copying data from selection of rows to different sheet based on cell string start and end

Tags: excel, vba

I have my data in columns A:L in Sheet2 and wish to copy each block based on the starting point, as certain cell text and the end point, again as certain cell text!

So in the example the cell start text should be "Tank Engine" and the cell end text would be "INFORMATION: Tank Engine". Therefore, column A:L, rows 1:18 should be copied into Sheet3 at cell A1, but only where the cell text exists as this can be dynamic. I need to reference column A to paste to in Sheet3, and copy only the rows that begin with "Tank Engine" and end with "INFORMATION: Tank Engine", which are rows 1:18. The next block would be Columns A:L, rows 25:41 based on the string "Weatherman" and this being pasted into Sheet3 Cell M:X etc.....

The rows are dynamic the columns are static..... I have tried many many snippets of VBA but this is quite particular so cannot find a good match!!

[image]

```
Sub Mike4()
Dim i As Long
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lastcolumn
    If Cells(1, i) = "Tank Engine" Then
        'lastrow = Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        lastRow = Columns(i).Find("INFORMATION: Tank Engine").Row
        Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).Copy Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the above to then paste the columns with the rows affected into a specific cell then to search for Weatherman as described above but need a starting point that something is working then be able to build on that...As stated previously I have lots of snippets of code but none accumulatively work for what I want to achieve if at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance...Many Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: PEH I have replied would you mind having a look then please?

Comment: Could you put workbook with sample data to some cloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMyStuff()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    'find start
    Dim FoundStart As Range
    Set FoundStart = wsSrc.Range("A:L").Find(What:="Tank Engine", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If FoundStart Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "start not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'find end
    Dim FoundEnd As Range
    Set FoundEnd = wsSrc.Range("A:L").Find(What:="INFORMATION: Tank Engine", LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=FoundStart)

    If FoundEnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "start not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wsSrc.Range(FoundStart, FoundEnd).Resize(ColumnSize:=12).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Or more elegant with a function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMyStuff2()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet 'define source
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'define destination
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Dim FindList As Variant 'defind search words
    FindList = Array("Tank Engine", "Weatherman")

    Dim i As Long

    Dim FindItm As Variant
    For Each FindItm In FindList
        Dim CopyRange As Range
        Set CopyRange = FindMyRange(wsSrc.Range("A:L"), FindItm, "INFORMATION: " & FindItm)

        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            CopyRange.Copy wsDest.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=i) 'note that if the first column uses merged cells the ColumnOffset:=i otherwise it is ColumnOffset:=i*12
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next FindItm
End Sub

Function FindMyRange(SearchInRange As Range, ByVal StartString As String, ByVal EndString As String) As Range
   'find start
    Dim FoundStart As Range
    Set FoundStart = SearchInRange.Find(What:=StartString, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If FoundStart Is Nothing Then GoTo ERR_NOTHING_FOUND

    'find end
    Dim FoundEnd As Range
    Set FoundEnd = SearchInRange.Find(What:=EndString, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=FoundStart)

    If FoundEnd Is Nothing Then GoTo ERR_NOTHING_FOUND

    Set FindMyRange = SearchInRange.Parent.Range(FoundStart, FoundEnd).Resize(ColumnSize:=12)

    Exit Function

ERR_NOTHING_FOUND:
    FindMyRange = Nothing
End Function
```